# Java HttpURLConnection trying to login with cookie

Tags: java, cookies

So am trying to login this website using java but for some reason its not working as expected i got the host and all that stuff but its not going to the account page with the cookie it still shows the login page and yes my account info is correct any help is great

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        String params = "loginEmail=private@hotmail.com&loginPassword=privatepassword&Submit=Sign+In";
        String urls = "http://www.filefactory.com/member/signin.php";

        URL url = new URL(urls);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Host", "www.filefactory.com");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Referer", "http://www.filefactory.com/member/signin.php");
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.101 Safari/537.36 OPR/25.0.1614.50");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" +
                Integer.toString(params.getBytes().length));
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");

        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        //Send request
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (
                connection.getOutputStream ());
        wr.writeBytes (params);
        wr.flush ();
        wr.close ();

        //Get Response
        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(line);
            response.append('\r');
        }
        rd.close();

        System.out.println(response.toString());

            // get the cookie if need, for login
            String cookies = connection.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");

            // open the new connnection again
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://www.filefactory.com/account/").openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookies);
        connection.addRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
        connection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.101 Safari/537.36 OPR/25.0.1614.50");
        connection.addRequestProperty("Host", "www.filefactory.com");

        System.out.println("Redirect to URL : " + "http://www.filefactory.com/account/");

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            html.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        System.out.println("URL Content... \n" + html.toString());
        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using : `String cookies = connection.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");`
Are you sure there is only one entry for that header? There could be more.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie

Try using chrome or firefox and try logging in manually to capture the request and response. That may give you some hints regarding what could be wrong.

Additionally you could use a tool to view the communication between your client and the server (unless you are already doing so)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell, not knowing the exact way that website works, but you should note that it sends you the cookies first when it presents the login page to you. When you send in your credentials you have to already send them together with the cookies, so that it knows to associate those credentials with this cookie.